# How do I access the time command in tmux from a shell script?

Tags: shell, tmux

I know how to use the time command in TMUX from the terminal directly:
(CtrlB + t)
But how can I do the same from a shell script ?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please share your code trials with error you getting

Comment: `time sleep 5` maybe?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The tmux time command writes straight to the terminal, so your script can't capture or otherwise make use of its output.

Answer (score 3):

Your script can invoke:

```
tmux clock-mode
```

...to display a clock in an already-running tmux instance. If there are multiple instances, a selector like `-t 0` can be used to select a specific tmux instance in which to display a clock.